# Google Sheets IF Function Query

Tags: google-sheets

I would like to do C1/A1 IF B1 cell is blank, IF it is not blank then do C1/B1.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
=iferror(If(B1,C1/B1,C1/A1))
```